# ReactJS - Labeling multi dimension array with chartJS-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

The chart below I'm trying to create:

[image]
I am trying to add labels to my chart but it's showing as undefined. When I enter

```
  labels: ["1", "2", "3"],
```

it gives the variable '1' to all the 1st variables. Any help on this would be brilliant. Thank you

```
const DummyChart = () => (
  <Doughnut data={data} options={options} width={360} height={360} />
);

 const data = {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Dummy 1",
      data: [487, 189],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "Dummy 2",
      data: [236, 764],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(0, 135, 136)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(0, 135, 136)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "Dummy 3",
      data: [811, 189],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};


const options = {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  rotation: Math.PI,
  circumference: Math.PI,
  cutout: 50
};

export default DummyChart;
```

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: Updated, showing all my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using point Labels on the chart. Additional chart js contains a label plugin which allows for more customization.

You can install it using this - npm i chartjs-plugin-labels.

Heres a link to a few demo's - https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/

Answer (score 2):

As per `react-chartjs-2` examples there is a separate key named `labels` for that. You also have to use the `tooltips` options so you will be able to customize your labels. See the working example I made below:

```js
var Doughnut = reactChartjs2.Doughnut;

const DummyChart = () => ( <Doughnut data={data} options = {options} width={360} height={360} />);

const data = {
  labels: [
    'Dummy 1',
    'Dummy 2',
    'Dummy 3',

  ],
  datasets: [{
      data: [487, 1000],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      data: [236, 1000],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(0, 135, 136)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(0, 135, 136)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      data: [811, 1000],
      backgroundColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderColor: ["rgba(0, 193, 189)"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};


const options = {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: false
  },
  rotation: Math.PI,
  circumference: Math.PI,
  cutout: 50,
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(item, data) {
        return data.labels[item.datasetIndex] + ' ' + data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].data[0] + '/' + data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].data[1]
      }
    }
  }
};
ReactDOM.render( 
  <DummyChart /> ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/chart.js@2.6.0/dist/Chart.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/react-chartjs-2@2.1.0/dist/react-chartjs-2.js'>
</script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but it makes all the rows show as dummy 1.

Comment: @Hughesey, that's another issue. Fixed it for you. See the updated snippet.

Comment: I do appreciate the help. I need each arch to have it's own label. Such as Arch 1 is dummy 1 and is at 487/1000, and dummy 2 is 236/1000 and so on.

Comment: @Hughesey, I've modified the snippet completely. I've create a custom label using `tooltips` option. Now it should display exactly what you need.